# Bootstrap label-primary padding with linebreaks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap label that displays a rather long information text to the user, like so:

https://www.bootply.com/sHlWvXWiD7

This works as long as the display area is large enough. Once you start resizing the browser window, and bootstrap kicks into action, the text becomes unreadable. This is probably caused by the padding that is ignored. I have tried to work with line height, but its not what i want.

Comment: line-height was working.. check this: https://www.bootply.com/jVXPvUJw5N

Comment: You are misusing the label class. It is not supposed for long text containers. Better implement this with custom css.